# SSRS 2008 Charts - Data Fields Aggregating?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, aggregate

I'm experimenting with printing a report with a Step-Line Chart on it for one of our clients.  The set up and implementation all seem pretty straight forward, but I find myself getting caught up on the fact that the chart doesn't seem able to display a raw data value, but rather needs to perform an Aggregate function on the Value-axis data.

For example assume we have a query that returns 3 columns: TagName, DateTime, Value.

- Series: TagName
- Category: DateTime
- DataField: Value

I basically just want to display a chart organized by TagName (easy), with the X and Y chart values being DateTime and Value, respectively.  Am I missing something?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

I set a sample chart up with the fields set as you said

- Series: TagName
- Category: DateTime
- DataField: Value

Change the X-Axis to a scalar value, and format the axis labels as required.

[image: Chart Example]

Regarding your aggregate data question. If you have multiple values sharing TagName and DateTime, then you need to aggregate them in some way, either `Sum` or `Count`, or if you want to just display a single value then use `First` or `Last`

Comment: Hmm, ok.  So seeing as no TagName-DateTime set will ever match I can use either Sum OR First (for example) and still get good results, because there is only one data point per.  Cool.  Thanks man!